# back4App, query using alamofire

Tags: mysql, swift, alamofire, back4app

I'm trying to make a query request on my database in back4app using Alamofire.
(i don't want to use Parse, for study purpose).
My DB has 2 simple field , Name and Age

[image: DB]

I would like to send .get request using AF to obtain the data relative to a specific name.

I'm able to retrive all data in the DB with the following function:

```
 func readData(){
        AF.request(url!, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { json in
            print(json)
        
    }
 }
```

as per the back4app documentation in order to query a specific field is reported:
" specified the Parameters  where URL parameter constraining the value for keys. It should be encoded JSON"

here my test:

```
func readDataQuery(name: String){
        let param: [String: String]  = [
                 "Name": name
        ]
        AF.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: param, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { json in
            print(json)
        
    }
    }
```

but it return an error:

```
success({
    code = 102;
    error = "Invalid parameter for query: Name";
})
```

how can I write the parameters to pass at the request?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no such query parameter called "Name". In order to get objects via a condition, you would have to use the "where" clause like this.

```
let param: [String: String]  = ["where": "{"Name":"Meimi"}"]
```

For more information please visit this website

https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#query-constraints